# Central deposit for recommendation letters

Tags: recommendation-letter

A while back, I remember seeing a service, and I believe more than one, that claimed that they would store letters of recommendation for you and send them on your behalf or the person writing the letter. That is, the letter writer would submit the letter to them, and then you could submit that same letter to different places requiring a similar letter through them, all without you ever seeing the letter. The idea is to avoid repeating work for the writer and avoiding constant asking for letters for the applicant.

The thing is, my Google-fu has completely failed me and I cannot find them again. Does anyone know what I'm talking about?

Comment: Maybe review your browser or Google Search history

Comment: Interesting question, this seems like a potentially useful service. (particularly for letter-writers)

Answer (score 2):

In mathematics, mathjobs.org fills this role.

Answer (score 1):

[academicjobsonline.org](https://academicjobsonline.org/) does that, for instance: Letter writers can upload "generic letters" which serve for all applications of an applicant.  Of course, this requires that the corresponding application process is done through this platform by whoever advertises the job.

Comment: So they will not allow you to store previous letters of reference and send them out to different institutions the way Interfolio does?

Answer (score 1):

Interfolio.  In general you have to pay for it, though a few departments will pay them instead.  They will try to upload or mail to whatever system you want.